# jQuery Tabs and Button in IE6

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, internet-explorer-6

I have an issue in IE6 (no surprise) where button elements are hovering in IE6 rather than being positioned correctly in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. This seems only to occur when clicking a non-selected tab.

The CSS and JS are the latest versions of JQuery UI.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

[Edit] My apologies, I forgot to add a screenshot :)

[image]

The issue seems to arise when the content is dynamically generated and I select another tab. When the content generates again (cookie keeps the current selected tab on page refresh), the content moves to the correct place.

Comment: interesting question, would like to know what the community has to tell about this :)

Comment: Oh man IE6...I say we should wipe it from the face of the compatibility universe...

Comment: well without code theres not that much we can tell you... have you tried `* {zoom:1;}` usually fixes a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the button elements hovering on the jQuery UI tabs demo on the website? (In IE6)

Things that help with solving this are,

- What other javascript files you are using?
- What other css you are using?

EDIT: (After accepted)

> It is recommended to load CSS files before Javascipt files, but it rarely
>   makes a difference.
>
> jquery.js should always be loaded
>   FIRST, before anything else that
>   depends on jQuery. Similarly, you
>   should always load jquery.ui.js before
>   any ui widgets, like ui.tabs.js.
>   Layout utilizes jquery.ui, but is not
>   a ui widget, so it really doesn't
>   matter whether it loads before or
>   after jquery.ui.

Comment: Seems to be the order in which the JS is called is the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the order in which the JS is called is the issue!